# Get item from list of a DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, http, blazor, blazor-webassembly

OnInitializedAsync I get a list of my customers with an http request. It will load one item to the list. How can I get this item to my other variable? Code below.

```
    private List<CustomerDTO> customers { get; set; }
    private CustomerDTO customer { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        customers = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<CustomerDTO>>(TestRoutes.Customer.GET_Customers());
        customer = ?
    }
```

Comment: Do you have specific condition to filter customer from List<CustomerDTO>?

Comment: What do you mean by specific condition? I want to filter it by Id (or GUID).

Comment: The condition would be that the `Id` is equal to a specific value. Do you know what that specific value is? You can call `First` on your list to get a single item that satisfies the specified condition.

Comment: have you tried `customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "<ID that you have>")`

Comment: I just totally forgot about FirstOrDefault... Thank you.

Comment: Does it make sense that there would not be a match to the `Id`? If not, call `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @John you're totally true. There is no match to the Id obviously. I used `customer = customers.First(); Works now!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification in the comments I tried to use `customer = customers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == <insert Id here>);`

Of course I had no Id to compare. So as @John mentioned in the comments, I used `customer = customers.First();` to get that single customer from the List